# Download automation and monkey swinging to next page

Tags: bash, download

So here's what I got at the moment

```
#!/bin/bash
#USAGE: bash myDown.sh example.org
#get url
START=$1

while [[ $# -gt 0  && -z $START ]]; do

#get download url
DOWN=$(wget -O- "$START" | grep "download.php?id=*" | grep -io 'href=['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*['"'"'"]' | cut -d\" -f2)
#run download
wget -O "$START" "$DOWN"
#get next page
NEXT=$(wget -O- "$START"  grep -m1 "\"next\"" | grep -io 'href=['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*['"'"'"]' | cut -d\" -f2)
#goto next
START=$NEXT
done
```

So in my mind this should get the response from the url, grep it for $DOWN and $NEXT, run $DOWN and monkeyswing to NEXT as next while rounds START.

When running it against a downloaded example.php from the site in question the greps work fine, manual wget via terminal with the DOWN url works just as well as clicking the download button on the site would, but something's not working as imagined.

Can you see what I did wrong or how I could do things better?
I initially thought about doing a recursive wget but the download is all via a "central" /download.php?id=... and the id's aren't all incremental for the respective books so I chose to monkeyswing via grepping from the next button.

When the last chapter is reached there is no next button so [ -z $START ] should terminate, but it isn't even running so far
Kinda lost here.
Thanks!

```
$ bash -x myDown.sh "https://www.example.html" 
+ START=example.html
+ [[ 1 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ -z example.html ]]
+ :
```

site substituted

Comment: A `continue` at the last statement of the loop is redundant. Aside from this, I suggest that you fix  the syntax errors first. It does not make sense to discuss errors in program logic, if the program is not even syntactically correct. Paste your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to do this. After this is done, run your program with `-x` turned on, and show the output.

Comment: Don't put code and program output into a comment, especially if it covers several lines. Put it (properly formatted) into the question. Note that there is a tiny _Edit_ link below the question which you can use to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from the trace that the loop body is never entered.

`-z $START` is true, if `START` is empty. However, `START` is set to `example.html`. THerefore `-z $START` is false and the condition for the *while* is also *false*.

You have to negate the condition:

```
[[ $# -gt 0  && -n $START ]]
```

`-n` tests for *not empty*.